How to create an SSRS expression that ignores the report parameters?
For illustrative purposes, say I have the below dataset



Color
Sale




Blue
$1


Black
$1


Green
$1



In my SSRS report, I have an area labeled total sales so users can view the overall sales at all times, but I also have a parameter that filters on the color column. So with the parameter set to black, my total sales box will only show $1 but I would like it to bypass the filter and still show $3. The current total sales expression is the below:
= Sum(Fields!Sale.Value, "Dataset") + 0

SQL Server 2008, and with it SSRS 2008, reached end of life over 5 years ago; it is long past time you implemented your finalised upgrade plan (that should have been finalised in 2018). Using such an outdated, insecure, version is a significant risk to you, other users and your clients.

Sounds like you are filtering as part of the SQL expression. Instead return all the rows and filter in the tablix.

You can always add a second DataSet to the report, which queries (and is used to display) total sales.

I was able to figure this out after posting the question (although I have pondered on it for a few days now). Dale K's comment was the route I went with. I removed the filtering from the SQL expression and instead did it on the row group level, which produced the result I needed.
